# When to use Exception

Tags: exception

I have a Form or Page and some privileges (Save, Modify, Delete etc.) assigned to a user that is using this page, let's assume this user only has Save and Modify privileges.

When user clicks Delete button, which he is not privileged to, I want to display a message to him to inform him that he doesnt have this privilege, how should my code look like?

Option 1

```
If(loggedUser.Privileges.Contains(PrivilegeTypes.Delete) == false)
{
     MessageBox.Show("You dont have delete privilege!");
     // Log that user tried to delete without permission etc
     return;
}
```

Option 2

```
try
{
     If(loggedUser.Privileges.Contains(PrivilegeTypes.Delete) == false)
     {
         // Throw custom exception
         throw new UngrantedPrivilegeException(PrivilegeTypes.Delete, "Invalid privilege exception");
     }
}
catch (UngrantedPrivilegeException ex)
{
     if( ex.PrivilegeType == PrivilegeTypes.Delete) 
     {
          MessageBox.Show("You dont have delete privilege!");
          // Log that user tried to delete without permission etc
     }
}
```

Comment: Option 2 is the best because when ever the program execute first it'll execute try condition when ever your program throw the critical error or exception you'll know if you use ypur email address in catch condition.

Comment: @user2727841: Option 2 is absolutely ***not*** the best.  The condition is checked appropriately in the first option, the second option adds an exception and then immediately catches that exception solely for the purpose of logic flow.  There is absolutely no need for the overhead of an exception in this case.

Comment: I would say go with option one it pretty much gets the job done and does nothing else

Comment: well its up to you but in very complex programs we use try and catch conditions.

Comment: @user2727841: If you use them like this, your "very complex programs" are incorrectly designed and probably a lot more complex than they need to be.

Comment: some times we face many problems at live server thats why we use try and catch condition remember at local computer you face less problems but at live server, you can't imagine.

Comment: @user2727841: If this is how you write code, it's no wonder you face many problems in your production environment.  Simpler code is easier to support.

Comment: Ok sir option1 is best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is absolutely no reason to use an exception in this case.  There is nothing *exceptional* about what the code is doing, and simple conditional logic is appropriate.

Consider the semantic logic of your first option:

```
Does the user have permission?
    Tell the user they don't have permission.
```

Now consider the semantic logic of your second option:

```
Try to check for permission
    Does the user have permission?
        The user does not have permission.
Did the user have permission?
    Tell the user they don't have permission.
```

Seems like a lot of redundancy in the second one, don't you think?  You're also adding more overhead to the runtime by throwing an exception for the *sole purpose* of *immediately* handling it, when all you really wanted to do was check a condition.  `if` statements exist to check conditions, there's no reason not to use one here.  (Indeed, you *are* using one even in your second example.)  It also pollutes the code with a lot of unnecessary things which distract from the basic business logic of what you're doing (checking a permission setting), making the code more difficult to support.

Don't use exceptions for logic flow.  Use them to handle unexpected things that shouldn't happen, not to determine the logic flow of things that are expected to happen.

Comment: what if i needed to add some more lines to the handling part, like logging that this user tried to use an ungranted permession etc. would you still think the same? also considering that the normal flow of the code is that the user has permission to do delete and the exception is that he doesnt have this premssion, would that make exception better?

Comment: @user2080257: You can add those lines inside the `if` block.  That's what the `{}` brackets are for, enclosing multiple lines of code.  And no, this is not an exceptional case.  If you present the user with the *option* to delete (even if that option is hidden in some way, it's still accessible through the program's interface) and then check the permission when they make the attempt, then the user is still using the system as designed.  There's no need for an exception here.

Answer (score 3):

In this case i would go for first option since i know what are the possibilities and no need of creating unwanted exception object as burden on memory.

Exception should be used to handle unknown run time errors, not for logic conditions.